# "ADB not found" error in Android Studio 3.1.2 with Device File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

I upgraded Android Studio to 3.1.2 and when I want to use the `Device File Explorer`, I got the "Error initializing ADB:Android Debug Bridge not found."error, however, my adb works fine in both cmd and powershell, how can I fix this error?From the error messages I find there is an Exception in a plugin called `Android Support` and on my computer its version is 10.3.1.2.
Flowing are the error messages:

```
ADB not found
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:140)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.adbimpl.AdbDeviceFileSystemService.start(AdbDeviceFileSystemService.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerController.setup(DeviceExplorerController.java:139)
    at com.android.tools.idea.explorer.DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(DeviceExplorerToolWindowFactory.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.ensureContentInitialized(ToolWindowImpl.java:573)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.getContentManager(ToolWindowImpl.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.processRequestFocus(RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.lambda$run$0(RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.doWhenExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.doWhenDone(ActionCallback.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.run(RequestFocusInToolWindowCmd.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowsPane$AddDockedComponentCmd.run(ToolWindowsPane.java:768)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.CommandProcessor.run(CommandProcessor.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.FinalizableCommand.finish(FinalizableCommand.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.ApplyWindowInfoCmd.run(ApplyWindowInfoCmd.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another program.
The problem was that another screen sharing program on my machine was opening an old ADB server, which leads to miscommunication between the program and the phone.

Comment: But on my computer the only program which uses ADB is Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when ADB was not authorized to access the device.
If Android Studio can initialize ADB without a device connected to your computer, then the problem is probably related to this issue.

To fix this, I started the adb server from the terminal, authorized it and the restarted Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, `File -> Project Structure -> Module -> Your projectname_android-> dependencies->modules sdk: (select api as android api platform),` then click Apply and OK.

And do `which adb` output in my case `/usr/local/bin/adb`
`ls -la` /usr/local/bin/adb

```
/usr/local/bin/adb -> <path to correct adb location which is mentioned in sdk in android studio.
```

After doing these steps issue was resolved.